# $f\in L^1_{\text{bc}}\left(\mathbb R\right)$ and $x^2f\left(x\right)$ bounded $\implies$ $\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}f\left(x+k\right)$ uniformly convergent

Tags: summation, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, uniform-convergence, harmonic-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$ be bounded, continuous, and let

$$\int\left|f\left(x\right)\right|\,dx<\infty.$$

> If $x^2f\left(x\right)$ is bounded, then
>   $$\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}f\left(x+k\right)$$
>   is uniformly convergent.

This is what I attempted: let

$$s_n\left(x\right)=\sum_{k=-n}^nf\left(x+k\right).$$

Then

$$\left|s_m\left(x\right)-s_n\left(x\right)\right|=\left|\sum_{n<\left|k\right|\leq m}f\left(x+k\right)\right|\leq\sum_{n<\left|k\right|\leq m}\left|f\left(x+k\right)\right|.$$

However, I do not know how to make the right hand side arbitrarily small to show that $\left(s_n\left(x\right)\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is uniformly Cauchy. Moreover, I do not know how to use the fact that $x^2f\left(x\right)$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write $f_k=f(x+k)$. The series $\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} f_k$ cannot converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ unless $f$ is identically zero. Indeed, for uniform convergence of $\sum f_k$  it is necessary (though not sufficient) that $\sup |f_k|\to0$ as $|k|\to\infty$. Clearly, $\sup_{\mathbb{R}} |f_k| = \sup_{\mathbb{R}}|f|$ is independent of $k$.

But it's true that the series converges uniformly on every bounded interval, say  $[-A, A]$. Continuity and integrability are not needed for this: it suffices to know that there is $M$ such that $x^2|f(x)|\le M$ for all $x$. Indeed, by the triangle inequality $|x+k|\ge |k|-A$ for $x\in [-A,A]$, which implies
$$
\sup_{[-A,A]} |f_k| \le \frac{M}{(|k|-A)^2},\quad \text{for }|k|>A, 
$$
hence the series converges uniformly by the Weierstrass M-test.

Comment: Is the claim then incorrect? Should it instead say that $\sum f_k$ is locally uniformly convergent?

Comment: As written, it's incorrect. But it's possible that it's correct in the context where the sum is only considered on $[0,1]$. After all, the purpose of this is to make a periodic function out of $f$, so why would we consider all values of $x$...

Comment: You are absolutely right. The context does mention that $g=\sum f_k$ is periodic, but that is it; the above claim is casually mentioned without justification.